# How to disable swiping to right for a particular item in a list of articles?

Tags: android

I have built an android app to display different articles. on swiping to right ,it takes you to the web fragment of the article. but after every four articles, I want to post Ads and disable the swiping feature for Ads, again the swiping should be enabled for the rest of the articles. only for Ads,swiping to the right should be disabled. How do I achieve this?

what we tried is:

```
 mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

                                                   }    
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                                                       Toast.makeText(context, "Position"+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                       BaseFragment fragment = (BaseFragment) mAdapter.getItem(position);
                                                       if (fragment != null) {
                                                           fragment.pageSelected(position);
                                                       }  

                                                       if (position != 2) {


                                                           BrowserFragment browserFragment = (BrowserFragment) mAdapter.getItem(2);
                                                           if (browserFragment != null) {
                                                               browserFragment.browserDeselected();
                                                           }

                                                       }
                                                  }

                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) { 
 if (newsElement.getSeoLink()==null) {
      mViewPager.disableScroll(true); // this method disables swiping features for all the articles

        Toast.makeText(context, "central", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } 

                                                   }
                                               });
```

I am trying to disable on the condition when seolink is null but the function mViewPager.disableScroll(true); disables the swiping feature for all the articles. How do I fix this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because you're disabling swiping for the whole `ViewPager` and you're not enabling it again. What you need to do is to disable or enable the scrolling everytime the item changes.

1. You are actually getting the selected `Fragment` in onPageSelected()
2. So in that method you should check if its either an `article Fragment` or an `Ad Fragment` and based on that enable or disable the swiping.

Comment: Hello,Thanks for your reply but we don't have two separate fragments  like article and ad. we have only one fragment, we are differentiating article and ads based on the parameter called 'Seolink'.